# Why returns with false value although the regex pattern is correct, and thestring is also

Tags: c#, regex

So I have a function which decide the input ( which is a third type grammar) is correct or isn't. Although the components are good the fucttion returns false every time.

Here's the code:

```
 public bool isCorrectGram(List<string> rules)
    {
        bool find=false;
        Regex rgx=new Regex("[a-z]{1}[A-Z]{1}");
        Regex rgx2 = new Regex("[a-z]{1}");
        foreach(string line in rules)
        {
            List<string> temp = line.Split('|', '→').ToList<string>();
            foreach(string rule in temp)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(rule);
                if (rule!=temp[0]&&(!rgx.IsMatch(rule) || !rgx2.IsMatch(rule)))
                {
                    find = false;
                }
                else find= true;
                if (!find)
                    break;
            }
            if (!find)
                break;
        }
        return find;
    }
```

And a correct sample input is:

```
S→aA
A→a
```

(so every rule is correct which contains one small and one capital letter or just one small)

[EDIT]
the problem is the regex. I have a pattern which only match with strings like a or aB

Comment: Show the code where you are inputting a string list.  When I input S and A it returns true for me.

Comment: I tried it with the sample I wrote and it's false. The left side is always a capital letter, but the right is can be small and capital or just small.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding.  I copied and pasted the method above and called it with Console.WriteLine(isCorrectGram(new List<string>{"S", "A"}).ToString());  This returned "True" to my console.

Comment: But I want to test a whole grammar. I think the | is the problem  but why?

Comment: Why `|` doesn't work is a (possible) third problem. The first problem is with your `if` condition - which returns false if *any* of your two regexes fails to match - rather than if *both* of them fail to match. The second is with the regexes themselves, which only check that the string *contains* the characters - "S→54367bfddA4523" would match the first regex too, just because it contains the character sequence `dA` in the middle of it.

Comment: then the regex is the problem. Which is the correct form?

Comment: Posted an answer with more explanation - and some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a small error inside your loop:

The expression in the if-statement

```
if (rule!=temp[0]&&(!rgx.IsMatch(rule) || !rgx2.IsMatch(rule)))
```

should rather be something like

```
if (rule!=temp[0]&&(!rgx.IsMatch(rule) && !rgx2.IsMatch(rule)))
```

or

```
if (rule!=temp[0]&& !(rgx.IsMatch(rule) || rgx2.IsMatch(rule)))
```

**Why?**

The second part of your the expression *always* evaluates to `true`! You are testing whether `rgx` is not a match or `rgx2` is not a match. For *any* string in the universe, at least one of those two will not match!

I am pretty sure that you actually wanted to check if *both* of them do not match and only *then* set `find` to `false`, right?

**Last but not least**

Actually your code could use some further improvement:

- maybe use one regex matching all valid strings instead of two that you always both check
- I hope you don't use `rule!=temp[0]` to check if this is the first iteration of the loop... dangerous! (ignore this point though, if this is really the behaviour you want, so you can have strings like "♥→♥|a")
- control flow: use `return false` instaed of having an extra variable breaking out of the loops

Comment: ohhhh right, looking at your comment from that angle... makes total sense :-D

Comment: Thanks, although I still don't think it does - I'll delete it, it just confuses me - so most likely everyone else too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues here...

**The if condition**

```
if (rule != temp[0] && (!rgx.IsMatch(rule) || !rgx2.IsMatch(rule)))
{
    find = false;
}
```

Ignoring the first bit, which simply ensures you're only checking the part after `→`...

```
!rgx.IsMatch(rule) || !rgx2.IsMatch(rule)
```

... means you'll return `false` if the rule fails to match *either of the regexes*. In other words, to return true, it will have to match *both*.

Which `a` obviously doesn't - it doesn't match the first regex. The condition you want is really:

```
!(rgx.IsMatch(rule) || rgx2.IsMatch(rule))
```

... meaning, return `false` if the rule fails to match *both regexes*.

**The regular expressions**

Now, as for `aA`, it *will* match the first regex, obviously, but it will also match the second, because `[a-z]{1}` just means that the string has to *contain* a single character `a-z`. To match only a string *consisting* of that single character and nothing else, you'd need e.g. `^[a-z]{1}$` - or simply `^[a-z]$`.

You can also combine the two regexes into one to simplify: `^[a-z][A-Z]?$`

```
^      = assert start of string
[a-z]  = match 1 lowercase character
[A-Z]? = match 0 or 1 uppercase characters
$      = assert end of string.
```

**Readability**

On a side note, this is one of those cases where the "single exit" way of thought (i.e., avoiding using return in the middle of a method) doesn't help anyone in my opinion. With the above fixes and simplified by ignoring the "single exit" way of thought:

```
public bool isCorrectGram(List<string> rules)
{
    Regex rgx = new Regex("^[a-z][A-Z]?$");
    foreach(string line in rules)
    {
        // The compiler can infer the generic type (<string>) for `ToList()`.
        List<string> temp = line.Split('|', '→').ToList();
        foreach (string rule in temp)
        {
            if (rule != temp[0] && !rgx.IsMatch(rule))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```